# changing EPR in Axis2 wsdl

Tags: java, servlets

I am creating simple pojo webservice like TemperatureConversion. I was able to make deploy it and generate wsdl from it.

The problem is that I want to change the EPR / address from "http://172.x.x.x:8080/MyWebservice/services/TemperatureConversion" to "http://172.x.x.x:8080/MyWebservice/TemperatureConversion"

Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Removed tags relating to axis, since this is a much more general question about servlet paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done it.
refer to this link
 
"http://amilachinthaka.blogspot.com/2010/01/changing-axis2-application-path.html"
**it was not a very general question, required a change in axis2 config file. its actually related to axis2.**
-sandeep

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can if you properly configure your web.xml

Comment: yes, i tried doing it.

this is what i changed in the web.xml
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/web/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

to make the EPR as "http://172.x.x.x:8080/MyWebservice/web/TemperatureConversion". it works. but when i access the wsdl from the location "http://172.x.x.x:8080/MyWebservice/web/TemperatureConversion?wsdl" then in the wsdl this is printed:
 <soap12:address location="http://172.16.4.163:8080/MyWebService/services/TemperatureConversion" />

so the auto generated wsdl does not reflect the changes.

any pointers?